# How to transform an object of Promise to object of Observable and still have typescript typings?

Tags: typescript, promise, rxjs, typescript-typings

I am having an object of Promise. I like to transform all of them into observable (rxjs) but I want to keep the typing.
This way is not working:

```
const methods = {
    func1: (): Promise<boolean> => {
        return Promise.resolve(true)
    },
    func2: (num: number): Promise<number> => {
        return Promise.resolve(num)
    }
};

const mapItToObservable = (methods) => {
    return Object.keys(methods).reduce((acc, key) => {
        acc[key] = from(acc[key])
        return acc;
    }, {})
}

const methodsInObservable = mapItToObservable(methods)

methodsInObservable.func1.subscribe(d => console.log('d'))
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if my reading of this question is correct, you want to map an object containing functions returning promises to  functions returning observable.

You can make the types work out using a mapped type to map the properties of the original type and a conditional type to extract the parameters and the result type and then use it to create the new function signature:

```
type MapToObservable<T extends Record<string, (...args: any[]) => Promise<any>>> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends (...args: infer P) => Promise<infer R> ? (...args: P) => Observable<R> : never
}
```

The function itself needs to correctly call the promise function and return the observable:

```
const methods = {
    func1: (): Promise<boolean> => {
        return Promise.resolve(true)
    },
    func2: (num: number): Promise<number> => {
        return Promise.resolve(num)
    }
};

type MapToObservable<T extends Record<string, (...args: any[]) => Promise<any>>> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends (...args: infer P) => Promise<infer R> ? (...args: P) => Observable<R> : never
}

const mapItToObservable = <T extends Record<string, (...args: any[]) => Promise<any>>>(methods: T) => {
    return Object.keys(methods).reduce((acc, key) => {
        acc[key] = function (...args: any[]) {
            return from(methods[key].call(this, ...args))
        }
        return acc;
    }, {} as Record<string, (...args: any[]) => Observable<any>>) as any as MapToObservable<T> ;
}

const methodsInObservable = mapItToObservable(methods)

methodsInObservable.func1().subscribe(d => console.log('d'))
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=30&ssc=61&pln=6&pc=1#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-GKaP1Y6NLP2RwuUvJ9Kd9nEroIOAEAhcFIBDHiyUSO7j-TjppJM7IRs6e4Yqi6M8Zf3wxHIkMYsW6-Vnkek9NGj0ReNSOAMgJW9kA+L4flCf5wiBSgdH0O0QDiBIyxTJ0QHdKDPR7R0PBdN1IJNbgk3LTBRhoYjUPQgjoK6XIEDyIoumYVh2E4LgNG-GJEKqCAugIVRUS4AByDQhL3IA)

Comment: Hardcore answer.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. i didn't know 'infer'. Thanks